# reducing the iframe size

Tags: iframe, iframe-resizer

I have a document with an Iframe within which is pointing to a different domain.

I am using IzFrameResizer library. Things work fine as long as it is one level, when I click a link in the iframe and if that is smaller than the original iframe page, iframe doesn't resize to the new page.

This is how I am using IFrameresizer

```
    iFrameResize({
                            log                     : false,
                            inPageLinks             : false,
                            heightCalculationMethod: 'max',
                            widthCalculationMethod: 'min',
                            sizeWidth: false
     }, 'myframe');
```

of course added the required libraries etc and it is working fine as long as i don't navigate to a new page within the iframe. I can access child page and I can access `parentIFrame` inside the child page (inside iframe). I tried calling `parentIframe.resize()` that also didn't help. B.T.W the iframe is hosting Angular app if that matters.

Comment: So just to verify, you can access the child page and you have it loading this [script](https://raw.github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/master/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js)?

Comment: Yes, I can access child page and I can access parentIFrame inside the child page (inside iframe). I tried calling parentIframe.resize() that also didn't help.
B.T.W the iframe is hosting Angular app if that matters.